# Strings in multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

How can i define an array in C language for strings without using pointers ? I am trying to create a chessboard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

char board[8][8] = {{ "R1 ", "N1 ", "B1 ", "QU ", "KI ", "B2 ", "N2 ", "R2 "},

                   { "P1 ", "P2 ", "P3 ", "P4 ", "P5 ", "P6 ", "P7 ", "P8 "},
                   { "","","","","","","",""},
                   { "","","","","","","",""},
                   { "","","","","","","",""},
                   { "","","","","","","",""},
                   { "p1 ", "p2 ", "p3 ", "p4 ", "p5 ", "p6 ", "p7 ", "p8" },
                   {"r1 ", "n1 ", "b1 ", "qu ", "ki ", "b2 ", "n2 ", "r2 "}};

}
```

I get an error " excess elements in char array initializer ". What should i do ? I am not allowed to using pointer.

Comment: You are placing strings and not chars as elements in your char array.

Comment: strings in C are char arrays. you can't get a string with no pointers.

Comment: Your initialiser it an initialiser for `char * board[8][8]`. It carries 8X8 "strings". `char[8][8]` expects 8X8 `char`s.

Comment: This is an 8x8 array of char: `char board[8][8]`.  You want an 8x8 array of strings: `char *board[8][8]`.

Answer (score 5):

You're defining a 2D array consisting of strings. Since strings themselves are arrays in C/C++, you're essentially creating a 3D array.

There are multiple ways to fix this:

- You can use `char *board[8][8]` to define an 8x8 array of pointers to the strings.
- You can use `char board[8][8][4]` to add the missing dimension (this uses the same memory no matter how long single entries are; each entry may have up to 3 characters plus 1 terminator).

As a side note, you should use the const keyword, as you typically won't want to modify the string contents.